# Primary key is not generated in JPA with app engine Java

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I have entity class "User" as shown below but its not generating primary key. I am using `JPA` in my app engine application and using app engine endpoints in my android client.

Enitty class:

```
@Entity
public class UserMaster {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    private String userName;
    private String fullName;
    private String userAvtarUrl;
    private String userAbout;
    private String userGender;


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getUserAvtarUrl() {
        return userAvtarUrl;
    }

    public void setUserAvtarUrl(String userAvtarUrl) {
        this.userAvtarUrl = userAvtarUrl;
    }

    public String getUserAbout() {
        return userAbout;
    }

    public void setUserAbout(String userAbout) {
        this.userAbout = userAbout;
    }

    public String getUserGender() {
        return userGender;
    }

    public void setUserGender(String userGender) {
        this.userGender = userGender;
    }
}
```

Endpoint persistence code :

```
@ApiMethod(name = "insertUserMaster")
    public UserMaster insertUserMaster(UserMaster usermaster) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try {
            if (containsUserMaster(usermaster)) {
                throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
            }
            mgr.persist(usermaster);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return usermaster;
    }
```

Android client

```
Userendpoint.Builder builder = new Userendpoint.Builder(
                        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                        new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                            public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
                            }
                        });

                Userendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
                        builder).build();

                User objUser = new User();

                objUser.setUserName(txtName.getText().toString());
                objUser.setUserEmail(txtEmail.getText().toString());

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                byte[] imgByte = out.toByteArray();
                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imgByte,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);
                objUser.setImage(encodedImage);

                User result = endpoint.insertUser(objUser).execute();
```

Please guide me where i am lacking. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If using JPA and GAE/Datastore either use all JPA annotations, or all as a vendor-extension use all JDO annotations. You cannot mix and match.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was mixing JPA and JDO but now i am just using JPA but then also its not working. I edited my code.

Comment: But "not working" doesnt really tell us much. The log will tell you a lot about what is sent to the datastore (and you present no actual JPA persistence code either). An object after persist will have an id (whether that is 0, or some other value) and you can print that out too. But when debugging the LOG should be your first point of call

Comment: if i don't set `userId` then it doesn't insert record in DB and i don't want to set my id programatically. I want that it should be autogenerated. I have already posted my entity persist code which i am using from android client.

Comment: I'm talking about JPA persist code, which maybe is hidden by this EndPoint stuff, but at the end of the day nobody here knows what that is calling. As already mentioned, the LOG is where you should look (when you have it set to IDENTITY).

Answer (score 0):

May be your database server does not provide the auto id generation.

**IDENTITY**

- `IDENTITY`, it is depend on the Database to auto generate.
- Some DB Server Like, `MySQL` or `Microsoft SQL Server` do provide `ID` generation for the primary key field during insertion.

The common way is to use the `IdGeneratorStrategy.TABLE`. It is not depend on DB.

Answer (score -1):

In my case problem was in method "containsUserMaster(usermaster)" 
Method check existing in way like this:

```
UserMaster item = mgr.find(UserMaster.class, userId);
```

Problem that until add operation not complete, userId will be null, and because program stops with NullPointerExeption..
I'm add userId checkinq on null - and this solves the problem